# Php find a part of string using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get a the part of string of an email after @ using regular expression.
For example, I have the string 'mirko@gmail.com' and i want to get 'gmail.com'.
I wrote /^@./
but doesn't work-
I wrote

```
preg_match('/^@./', $string, $output);
print($output);
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: What is the reason behind down-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why regex for this kind of simple task? use `strpos` with the combination of `substr` or just used `explode()` with `@` as first parameter as directed by other answers.

```
$email_string = "mirko@gmail.com";    
$result = substr($email_string, strpos($email_string, "@") + 1);    
echo $result ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several mistakes. First, with the caret you're telling you want the @ symbol to be first in the string. So for an email that will never match. Then, you need to set a capturing group to actually get the part after the @. So it'd look like this:

```
<?php
$mail = "mirko@gmail.com";
preg_match('/@(.+)/', $mail, $output);
print_r($output[1]); // gmail.com
```

**However**, this is such a simple task that you should not use a regular expresion. `explode()` will do:

```
<?php
$mail = "mirko@gmail.com";
$mailArray = explode("@", $mail);
print_r($mailArray[1]); // gmail.com
```

Comment: Can you tell me the reason behind down-voting my post?

Comment: I didn't? Might have been a mistake. Did you delete it?

Comment: @SahilGulati undelete your answer, I will of course remove downvote if it was mine.